# How to retreive one information from a localStorage key?

Tags: reactjs, axios, local-storage

Is it possible to retreive one information from a localStorage key ?

I have a key containing for example various information about the user after a connection :

```
{"id":1,"email":"AnEmail@Gmail.com","roles":SimpleUser,"iat":SomeNumber,"exp":SomeNumber}
```

And one of my axios request is : passing the user id in the URL, like this :

```
export const getAllOfSomething = (userId) => axios.get(`${URL}/something/${userId}`,
{
    userId: userId,
});
```

Probably a stupid question but I'm still learning everything

EDIT : I store my key like this when a connection is good :

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        login(event.target.email.value, event.target.password.value).then(response => {
            const Token = response.data.accessToken;
            localStorage.setItem('UserToken', Token);
            User = jwt_decode(Token)
            localStorage.setItem('User', JSON.stringify(User))
             history.push({
                  pathname: '/',
             });
            window.location.reload(false);

        }).catch(err => {
            setErrorForm(err.response.data.message);
        });
    };
```

The first localStorage.setitem is to only store the JWT Token.

The seconde one, I decode this Token to retrieve all the information about the user and this is what i get in my localStorage after decode :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to retreive one information from a localStorage key ?
> The answer is yes, you can retrieve what's being stored.

Here's an example of storing an object :

```
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(object));
```

And that's how to retrieve it :

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
```

Here's also a functional example :

```
public static store(object: any, key: string) {
if (object === null || object === undefined) {
  return -1;
} if (key === null || key === undefined) {
  return -2;
}else {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(object));
  return 1;
}

public static retrieve(key:string){
if (key === null || key === undefined) {
  return null;
}
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the functional example but I should probably edit my question.
My question was more, can you get ONLY the user id, not all information from the key.
Because, if I use localStorage.getItem(MyKey) in the URL, It won't work.

Comment: Yes you can do that, you may want to use localstorage.getItem(MyKey).id

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that, when I try, I only get "undefined"

Comment: can you share with me the part when you stored the object please?

Comment: Can you try this, based on the functional example :
let user = // your user.
store( user, "key")
console.log(retrieve("key").id)

Comment: I edited my question  so you can see how I store my object.

Comment: try this JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User')).id

Comment: Oh yeah ! It work ! Yeah it's logic, I stringify my object but don't do parse after that.
Thanks you for your time !

Comment: My pleasure, happy coding!